# Jascript random background static page HTML

Tags: javascript, image, random

I try since 2 hours to change my PHP code into JavaScript for static page "html" but I see example and it's not work. I just want in load page change the backgroung image.

Could you help me?

That my code.

```
  window.onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new Array("images/lion.jpg","images/tiger.jpg","images/bear.jpg");

function choosePic() {
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
     document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
```

In my HTML

But nothing works.

Comment: Assuming that what you have put there is your only code, you just made a typo and forgot your closing bracket. For future though, you should add a lot more detail to your question. Like for example, your html file, the specific error you are getting etc. EDIT: I made a typo in the word typo before, I have lost all respect for myself at this point

Answer (score 0):

It working for me. Here is that code. You can refer to this code and check out whats going wrong **The possibility might be that you are giving wrong paths in your Array object, so instead of using those paths, copy paste the paths which I have used in array, check if it is working, if YES then you provided wrong paths in your Array and correct them.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id='myPicture' src=''>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = choosePic;

        var myPix = new Array('https://i.imgur.com/pbyO8uHb.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/KgVNwGhb.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/Tj1bKhLb.jpg')

        function choosePic() {
            
            var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
            document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it's work if i put script code into my html but if i put outside js "picture.js" and call it, that not work. Other script work perfectly